# T4 template: double.NaN not rendering correctly

Tags: c#, .net, t4, template-engine

I have a [T4 template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx), which creates a series of `static readonly` variables derived from a pre-defined data set.

If I pass `double.NaN` as a constructor argument, the template output renders as **`NaN`**, not **`double.NaN`**, as I would have expected.

**The relevant part of the template is:**

```
<#= double.IsNaN(element.MeltingPoint) ? double.NaN : element.MeltingPoint #>
```

Which results in the compiler error:
`The name 'NaN' does not exist in the current context`

If I manually change the code to read `double.NaN` then it compiles just fine.

**How can I force the output to read as the literal string `double.NaN`?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the result of calling `double.NaN.ToString()` (which the T4 Engine does in order to print the result in the generated file) is the string "NaN" (as a matter of fact, it is culture-specific).

If you want the literal string `double.NaN`, then use a string literal:

```
<#= double.IsNaN(element.MeltingPoint) ? "double.NaN" : element.MeltingPoint.ToString() #>
```

Comment: I think the OP wants the constant value double.NaN not a string literal.

Comment: right... so the literal will appear in the output file without the quotes which will then compile....

Comment: That's perfect, thanks! Funny, that was the first thing I tried before posting. In the end I had to delete the generated file, then "run custom tool", before it was regenerated properly. Anyway, your advice did the trick :-)

Answer (score -1):

Try using Double.NaN. Although I suspect that the T4 Engine will possibly pick that up too.

Comment: the OP is already using `double.NaN`. There's no difference in C# between `double` and `System.Double`. C# is not (crappy retarded) java.

Comment: But the T4 engine is not the same as the C# compiler is it?

Comment: the T4 engine compiles the templates into regular CLR classes and executes methods on them. code blocks between `<#=` and `#>` are evaluated as C# expressions.

Comment: As a matter of fact, these generated classes are derived from `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.TextTransformation` and implement a method called `TransformText()` which is executed by the T4 engine after the template has been pre-processed into a CLR class.